# Xamarin how to bind Arcsegment StartPoint

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvm

I want to make simple circle chart for observe datetime but I can not bind arcsegment's StartPoint to custom point. How to bind it?

```
 private Point startPointer;
    public Point StartPointer
    {
        get { return startPointer; }
        set { startPointer = value; OnPropertyChanged("StartPointer"); }
    }
    private bool isTrue;

    public bool IsTrue
    {
        get { return isTrue; }
        set { isTrue = value; OnPropertyChanged("IsTrue"); }
    }
```

These are my properties in ViewModel.

```
  <Path StrokeThickness="10">
                    <Path.Data>
                        <PathGeometry>
                           
                            <PathFigure StartPoint="{Binding  StartPointer, Mode=OneWay}">
                                <ArcSegment IsLargeArc="{Binding IsTrue}"  RotationAngle="-90" SweepDirection="Clockwise"
                       
                        Point="{Binding StartPointer,Mode=OneWay}" 
                        Size="40, 40">
                                </ArcSegment>
                            </PathFigure>
                        </PathGeometry>
                    </Path.Data>
                    <Path.Stroke>
                        <Color>blue</Color>
                    </Path.Stroke>
                </Path>
```

This is my Arcsegment which I need to bind properties..

Answer (score 0):

Add this:

```
Source = {x:Reference viewmodel}
```

Comment: Could you please expand the answer to explain why/how it solves the problem?

Comment: Which element do you put the Source value on and why does this work? I have my entire xaml item bound by using the ContentView.BindingContext set to my View Model class